# why does amazon ses ask for an email verification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

So I am relatively new to aws and so I had a couple of doubts.
I was trying to use Amazon SES to send mails and when I went to generate SMTP settings, it asks for an email. My Question is does amazon use the email that i give them(say me@example.com) to send the mails ?
What I am basically trying to ask is this: there is a 100 emails a day limit on gmail if u send mails through an SMTP. Will that limit be a problem if I use a gmail account for amazon SES verification? Also, will these emails appear in the 'sent' folder of my gmail account?

Comment: What limits gmail sets is something you should ask of gmail support.

Comment: But almost every email has an smtp limit. But if SES only for an email for verification, then it shouldn’t be a problem, right?

Answer (score 4):

From the page [Verifying Email Addresses in Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html)

> Amazon SES requires that you verify your email address or domain, to
>   confirm that you own it and to prevent others from using it. This
>   section discusses verifying individual email addresses. For
>   information about domain verification, see Verifying Domains in Amazon
>   SES.

[SES Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html) are documented on this page.

Being new to AWS you might not know their documentation is extensive and accurate. Google often finds the right documentation very easily.

**Update**

Yes, SES sends using an email address on a domain you own. SES is an email server. From the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/).

*Verify domains or email addresses: Before you can send an email using Amazon SES, you need to verify that you own the domain or address from which you will send email. To start the verification process, visit the Amazon SES console.*

Comment: my point is, it wont use my email account to send mails in any way, right?

Comment: @PranavSinghal please refer to the documentation quoted in the answer.

Comment: @Alfabravo if u could just tell me, that woould be much appreciated, I cant find it in the documentation

Comment: What are you using SES for if not to send emails? AWS won't send random emails to people if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: No, what I am asking is, the email that I give for verification, it wont be used for sending the mails,right? I mean it won't go from the outbox of the mail that I give them,right?

Comment: Please read the SES documentation carefully, then edit your question to more precisely ask what you can't work out for yourself. Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: i edited the question, can u undestand it now?

Comment: SES is an email server that sends emails from a domain you own. You verify the email address to prove you own that domain. Suggest you read the FAQ and basic information about SES again, linked from my updated answer.

Comment: @Tim U still dont get it, It wont send emails from my gmail account, right?
If I provide my-name@gmail.com as the verification email, it wont use this email to send the mails right? Coz this account has a 100 emails a day limit

Comment: If I don't get it that's because you haven't explained things well. You might also try being a bit more polite with people trying to help you. SES is an email server, why would it log into your gmail and send emails? Are you trying to have AWS SES send emails from your gmail account? I don't know if that's possible due to anti-spam provisions, but even if it's possible it's not a great idea. You should use your own domain, which means you need to [validate your domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html).

Comment: @Tim I am extremely sorry if I was rude. That was definitely not my intention. I just wanted to make sure that the 100 mails a day limit on gmail outbox(when using SMTp) won't be a problem if I use that with amazon SES

Comment: You can't use SES to send email from your gmail.com email address.